# Rails: Team has many workers but one must have a special position (director)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a Rails model that relates a team with its workers. The team should have many workers, but one of those workers should be the director of the team!

Here's what I have so far:

**Schema**

```
create_table "workers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.index    ["team_id"], name: "index_workers_on_team_id"
end

create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "director_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end
```

**Team**

```
has_many :workers, required: false
belongs_to :director, class_name: "Worker", foreign_key: "director_id"
```

**Worker**

```
belongs_to :team
has_one :team, foreign_key: "director_id"
```

### My major problems are:

- team.build_director associates the worker to it's team director but it does not set it has one if it's workers.

  ```
  irb(main):001:0> team = Team.new(name: "Major Team")
  => #<Team id: nil, name: "Major Team", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, director_id: nil>

  irb(main):002:0> team.build_director(name: "Alexander")
  => #<Worker id: nil, name: "Alexander", team_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

  irb(main):003:0> team.save
  => true

  irb(main):004:0> team
  => #<Team id: 1, name: "Major Team", created_at: "2016-07-28 20:43:28", updated_at: "2016-07-28 20:43:28", director_id: 1>

  irb(main):005:0> team.director
  => #<Worker id: 1, name: "Alexander", team_id: nil, created_at: "2016-07-28 20:43:28", updated_at: "2016-07-28 20:43:28">

  irb(main):006:0> team.workers
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
  ```
- by building a team from a worker I was expecting that the worker would be the team's director, but it fails on save .....

  ```
  irb(main):001:0> worker = Worker.new(name: "Jarvas")
  => #<Worker id: nil, name: "Jarvas", team_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

  irb(main):002:0> worker.build_team(name: "Assigned Team")
  => #<Team id: nil, name: "Assigned Team", goals: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, director_id: nil>

  irb(main):003:0> worker.save
  (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Team Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "teams" WHERE LOWER("teams"."name") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Assigned Team"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "workers" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Jarvas"], ["created_at", 2016-07-28 20:56:12 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-28 20:56:12 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "teams" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Assigned Team"], ["created_at", 2016-07-28 20:56:12 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-28 20:56:12 UTC]]
  (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  NoMethodError:   Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."director_id" IS NULL
  ```

Am I doing something really wrong? Or the things I want must be done manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not doing anything wrong, but this is behavior you need to define yourself. Rails doesn't know that the first team member should also be a director or that assigning a director should also add them to the team.  You have to configure that yourself.

How you do that is entirely up to you.  You could use hooks to make it happen automatically. Or you could create service objects such as `TeamDirectorBuilder` which would do both or you could add them to the team first and then have a `promote_team_member` method that promotes the given team member to the director position.

Which way is best is tough to say without knowing the rest of your app and use cases (for example, are you sure you'll never have a director who isn't on the team?).

Comment: I'm quite new to Rails so could you elaborate the hooks part?

Comment: By hooks I meant "active record callbacks." Like `before_save` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your team should only have one director you can use `has_one` in your model.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workers, -> { uniq }

  has_one :director, -> { where director: true}, source: :worker
end
```

The best read I came across on this topic was  [Fun with Rails has_one through association](http://dev.mikamai.com/post/113951227084/fun-with-rails-hasone-through-association). That post goes into more detail and further examples.

Comment: (sidenote) about my example in the model, not sure if this is completely correct, might have some error somewhere. Haven't tested it, just the basic idea